# Qtimer event not executing

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I'm trying my first play with Python timers for use with QT GUI's, but this simple example I have created is not triggering the 'update_time' event. 'start' is printed ok as expected.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime

def change_time(): 
        timer = QTimer()
        timer.timeout.connect(update_time)
        timer.start(1000)
        print("start")

def update_time():
        time = QTime.currentTime()
        #not executed
        print("executed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
change_time()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That `timer` gets garbage collected as soon as `change_time()` returns (so, immediately). At least, add a parent: `timer = QTimer(QtWidgets.QApplication.instance())`.

Comment: Thats perfect thanks. Can you add it as an answer I I can mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively to what @musicamante suggested you could also define the timer outside of the function so that if you ever decide to stop the timer, future calls to `change_time` can reuse the same timer and avoid creating a new one.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime

def change_time(timer): 
    timer.timeout.connect(update_time)
    timer.start(1000)
    print("start")

def update_time():
    time = QTime.currentTime()
    #not executed
    print("executed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    timer = QTimer()
    change_time(timer)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```